# Prove $a_0 = (-1)^n \det(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Say that $A \in M^{nxn} (F)$, and consider its characteristic polynomial $p_A(x)=\det(xI_n-A) = a_0+a_1+...+a_nx^n$.
>   Prove that $a_0 = (-1)^n\det(A)$

I don't know if it is just to do this, it looks too easy to be true:

$a_0=p_A(0)=\det(0-A)=\det(-A)=(-1)^n\det(A)$

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations, your work is fine.

$a_0$ is just the intercept which can be obtained by substituting $x=0$ in $p_A$. You have applied the property that $$\det(cA)=c^n \det(A)$$ correctly.

Comment: Thank you! Just I have a curious doubt about what you just said, I study statistics and in linear regression we saw the definition of the intercept, does it have something to do with it?

Comment: They refer to the same thing, the intersection of the curve with $y$-axis is called $y$-intercept. The intersection of the curve with the $x$-axis is called $x$-intercept.